# ssize_t is undefined

Tags: c, posix, gnu

In my code I'm using ssize_t but when I try to compile project I got 
error: unknown type name ‘ssize_t’; did you mean ‘size_t’?

To compile project I'm using cc -std=c11 -O3 
I'm including stdint.h and I've also tried stddef.h and others.

Do I have to use some flags or what?

Answer (score 13):

The "signed-`size_t`" is not part of standard C, instead it's specific to POSIX (Unix, BSD, Linux, etc) and it's in `sys/types.h`:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html

On Windows, `ssize_t` is not defined but `SSIZE_T` is - but I assume you're on a POSIX system.

Comment: Although correct, the link to the POSIX specs you give is quiet a bit outdated. The current one is [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html).

Comment: On top of this, there's unlikely any reason to use `ssize_t` except with the interfaces that return it, which will not be available unless you include a header that defines it.

Comment: @R.. Or if you want to create a function that returns a size and can report errors.

Comment: @alx That's a bad design, imo. Use a discriminated-union (aka _tagged union_) instead - it'll use the same amount of storage, but clearly signifies intent.

Comment: @Dai, that's how most of the standard C library and the POSIX functions and system calls are designed.  I don't think it's so bad.  In fact, I think the _tagged union_ is bad (because of performance).  I'm not sure how you plan to use a `union` without knowing which of the fields you can use, as it's Undefined Behavior.  You probably need a `struct` enclosing the `union` and giving information about the field to be used, and that's already a lot of overhead compared to a simple number that can be positive or negative to mean two different things.  Moreover, unsigned integers are very dangerous

Comment: ... Moreover, unsigned integers are very dangerous, as they silently wrap around. See <http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1428r0.pdf>. So I use `ssize_t` wherever I need to use a `size_t`, unless I have no option.  I know it adds portability issues, but I don't plan to program outside of a POSIX environment, anyway.